# what is the difference between these two arrays in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and sometimes when I follow tutorials I see different forms of assigning the arrays' keys, can anyone explain the difference between them.

## first way

```
$post [
'title' => 'First title',
'body'  => 'First body'
];
```

## Second way

```
$post [
'title', 'First title',
'body', 'First body'
];
```

Comment: The first is creating an array with 2 entries, each with a key/value pair, the 2nd is create an array with 4 entries, indexed 0 through 3, with values. Please refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php for all the information you could possible need about PHP arrays, and check this 3v4l for reference: https://3v4l.org/D0QJG. Note: Both are syntax errors, you need `$post = [ ... ]` (likely a copy-paste issue, missed the `=` for variable declaration)

Comment: sometimes when arrays are passed from the `Controller` to the `view` this way is used: 
`
return view ('show')->with('title', 'the first title')
                               ->with('body', 'the first body');
`

Comment: `->with()` is a Laravel function that translates what you pass into variables available in the specific view. It can take multiple parameters (`->with('title', 'The First Title')->with('body', 'The First Body')`), or a single array of parameters (`->with(['title' =>  'The First Title', 'body' => 'The First Body'])`). It's not quite the same as a normal array definition.

Comment: Either method would result in `$title`, which is `'The First Title'` and `$body`, which is `'The First Body'` being available in the view. It's up to you which approach you want to use.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for sharing, I have an unrelated question, What does flagging a comment mean in `stack overflow` I mean is it good or bad?
because sometimes I wish to draw the attention of the audience to 
certain comments to be good to look at in the same context.

Comment: No problem! Flagging a comment can be done to inform moderators of an issue with a comment. They will review and remove the comment if necessary. Generally it's not bad, the comment just gets removed, unless the comment is hate speech, which can get you penalized (not sure what the penalties are though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a Laravel thing, but has to do with PHP.

The first way is called an associative array. You should use this if there is a relation between the key before the `=>` and the value after it. You could get the title by writing `$post['title']`.

The second is an array where there are no relationships between the values. It's just a collection of the same type of thing. You could also write this like this:

```
0 = 'title',
1 = 'First title',
2 = 'body',
3 = 'First body'
```

If you had an array called `posts`, it would be most likely to look like a combination of the two. So a numeric array for all posts and a associative array for each posts.

```
$posts = [
    [
        'title' => 'First title',
        'body' => 'First body'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Second title',
        'body' => 'Second body'
    ],
];
```

Do some research into (PHP) arrays and you'll figure it out.